# Passive OS Fingerprint смена ОС

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy

Дано Ubuntu 16.04 сервер, на сервере подняты прокси (3proxy). При подключении через прокси с macbook, OS Fingerprint определяется как `Linux 3.11 and never [fuzzy]` (http://witch.valdikss.org.ru/)
На данный момент с помощью не сложных манипуляций с настройками ядра /etc/sysctl.conf, получается сменить на Android (`Linux 2.2.x-3.x [generic] [fuzzy]`) и Windows NT.

Какие параметры ядра подправить так что-бы http://witch.valdikss.org.ru/ определял соединение как `Mac OS X  [generic] [fuzzy]`

Сигнатуру можно подсмотреть тут https://github.com/ValdikSS/p0f-mtu/blob/master/p0f.fp#L339